# Python-Playwright,How to start in non-incognito mode?

Tags: playwright

I found that the default startup is in incognito mode, how to change this default setting, thank you

```py
def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    path = r"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    arg = ["--start-in-incognito"]
    user_data = r"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\\"
    # --start-in-incognito
    # ignore_default_args=[]
    # chrome
    # executable_path=path
    # user_data_dir=user_data
    browser = chromium.launch(channel="chrome", headless=False, executable_path=path)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.pause()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

I tried changing the *args* and *ignore_default_args* parameters without success.

Comment: Try this - https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context
You can use 'user_data_dir' to use the saved cookie and session data.
Please note that browser extensions will not be enabled in persistent context.
For testing browser with extensions - launch the browser and attach playwright to it - https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-connect-over-cdp.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't use the Inspector with the launch_persistent_context() method,I don't know if there is any way to satisfy this, I checked the official documentation and found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
context = rf'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default'
browser = await playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(context, channel='msedge', headless=False, args=['--start-maximized'], no_viewport=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be used with LaunchPersistentContextOptions with BrowserType.

Playwright-Java code:

```
try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {             BrowserContext brContext = playwright.chromium().
                      launchPersistentContext(Paths.get(""), 
                              new BrowserType.LaunchPersistentContextOptions().setHeadless(false).setChannel("chrome")); brContext.newPage().navigate("https://www.google.com);
```